# How to implement a stacked RNNs in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to implement an RNN using Tensorflow1.13 on GPU. Following the official recommendation, I write the following code to get a stack of RNN cells

```py
lstm = [tk.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128) for _ in range(2)]
cells = tk.layers.StackedRNNCells(lstm)
```

However, I receive an error message:

> ValueError: ('All cells must have a `state_size` attribute. received cells:', [< tensorflow.python.keras.layers.cudnn_recurrent.CuDNNLSTM object at 0x13aa1c940>])

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @qlzh727. Here, I quote the response:

Either StackedRNNCells or StackedRNNCells only works with Cell, not layer. The difference between the cell and layer in RNN is that cell will only process one time step within the whole sequence, whereas the layer will process the whole sequence. You can treat RNN layer as:

```py
for t in whole_time_steps:
  output_t, state_t = cell(input_t, state_t-1)
```

If you want to stack 2 LSTM layers to together with cudnn in 1.x, you can do:

```
l1 = tf.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequence=True)
l2 = tf.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128)
l1_output = l1(input)
l2_oupput = l2(l1_output)
```

In tf 2.x, we unify the cudnn and normal implementation together, you can just change the example above with tf.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequence=True), which will use the cudnn impl if available.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a Tensorflow bug and I would suggest creating an issue on Github. However, if you want to by pass the bug, you can use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as tk

lstm = [tk.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128) for _ in range(2)]
stacked_cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(lstm)
```

This will work but it will give a deprecation warning that you can suppress.