# TensorFlow 2 GRU Layer with multiple hidden layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am attempting to port some TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2. The old code used the now deprecated [MultiRNNCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/MultiRNNCell) to create a GRU layer with multiple hidden layers. In TensorFlow 2 I want to use the in-built [GRU Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU), but there doesn't seem to be an option which allows for multiple hidden layers with that class. The [PyTorch equivalent](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#gru) has such an option exposed as an initialization parameter, `num_layers`.

My workaround has been to use the TensorFlow RNN layer and pass a GRU cell for each hidden layer I want - this is the way recommended in the docs:

```
dim = 1024
num_layers = 4
cells = [tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(dim) for _ in range(num_layers)]
gru_layer = tf.keras.layers.RNN(
  cells,
  return_sequences=True,
  stateful=True
)
```

But the in-built GRU layer has support for CuDNN, which the plain RNN seems to lack, to quote [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn#rnn_layers_and_rnn_cells):

> Mathematically, RNN(LSTMCell(10)) produces the same result as
>   LSTM(10). In fact, the implementation of this layer in TF v1.x was
>   just creating the corresponding RNN cell and wrapping it in a RNN
>   layer. However using the built-in GRU and LSTM layers enables the use
>   of CuDNN and you may see better performance.

So how can I achieve this? How do I get a GRU layer that supports both multiple hidden layers and has support for CuDNN? Given that the inbuilt GRU layer in TensorFlow lacks such an option, is it in fact necessary? Or is the only way to get a deep GRU network is to stack multiple GRU layers in a sequence?

**EDIT:** It seems, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644112/795131) to a similar question, that there is indeed no in-built way to create a GRU Layer with multiple hidden layers, and that they have to be stacked manually.

Comment: What are these hidden layers, conceptually? Are they parallel? Are they serial? What do they do?

Comment: Thanks. I think this can be done using the Sequential model, wrapping multiple GRU Layer instances. So it's serial/sequential, I guess. Like the answer linked to in my edit. I'm trying to achieve what is already achievable using the RNN class with a list of cells - a stack of layers, a deeper network. But with CuDNN optimization. The docs state the latter is only available for the in-built GRU Layer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it seems the only way to achieve this is to define a stack of GRU Layer instances. This is what I came up with (note that I only need stateful GRU layers that return sequences, and don't need the last layer's return state):

```
class RNN(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, dim, num_layers=1):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.dim = dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        def layer():
            return tf.keras.layers.GRU(
                self.dim,
                return_sequences=True,
                return_state=True,
                stateful=True)
        self._layer_names = ['layer_' + str(i) for i in range(self.num_layers)]
        for name in self._layer_names:
             self.__setattr__(name, layer())

    def call(self, inputs):
        seqs = inputs
        state = None
        for name in self._layer_names:
            rnn = self.__getattribute__(name)
            (seqs, state) = rnn(seqs, initial_state=state)
        return seqs
```

It's necessary to manually add the internal rnn layers to the parent layer using `__setattr__`. It seems adding the rnns to a list and setting *that* as a layer attribute won't allow the internal layers to be tracked by the parent layer (see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28748#issuecomment-493322794) answer to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28748) issue).

<del>I hoped that this would speed up my network. Tests on Colab have showed no difference so far, if anything it's actually slightly *slower* than using a straight RNN initialized with a list of GRU cells. I thought that increasing the batch size from 10 to 64 might make a difference, but no, they still seem to be performing at around the same speed.</del>

**UPDATE**: In fact there *does* seem to be a noticeable speed up, but only if I don't decorate my training step function with `tf.function` (I have a custom training loop, I don't use `Model.fit`). Not a huge increase in speed - maybe about 33% faster, with a batch size of 96. A much smaller batch size (between 10 to 20) gives an even bigger speed up, about 70%.